# Jasper Reports subreport text alignment is wrong only when in main report

Tags: jasper-reports

When I preview my jasper subreport, text is aligned to the right (what I want).
[image: subreport row]

But when it is used in the main report, text is aligned to the left

[image]

On both reports, per element styling is used, set in Jasper Studio.
The jrxml per element looks like...

```
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" markup="html">
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col_1_initials}]]>   </textFieldExpression>
```

The element including the subreport looks like

```
<band height="161" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <subreport isUsingCache="false" runToBottom="false">
            <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="595" height="161" uuid="4e6fb330-c43f-4d47-b7aa-6884dad63d14"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("weekPairs")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["weeksubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
```

I'm not using report Style Templates because for a reason I can't diagnose, Jaspersoft Studio crashes instantly trying to assign a style template.

What about the main report ovverides the subreport text-aligment and what would I have to change in the source to fix this?

**EDIT**

In the report designer->properties of a jrxml file there is a checkbox for "Derive Attributes". I've tried that both on and off, but nothing changed.

Comment: Why do you have `markup="html"`?

Comment: that was just the last one I tried. I tried none also. The possibiities I know of are html, none, styled, rtf